# Use JQ to parse JSON array of objects, using select to match specified key-value in the object element, then convert to CSV

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

Use JQ to parse JSON array of objects, using select to match specified key-value in the object element, then convert to CSV.

**Data Source:**

```
{
  "Other": [],
  "Objects": [
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test 123",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectElementUnit": "1"
    },
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 1",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectElementUnit": "2"
    },
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 2",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectElementUnit": "5"
    }
  ],
  "Language": "en-US"
}
```

**JQ command to extract**

```
jq -r '.Objects[] | select(.ObjectElementName | contains("ABC"))'
```

**Output given (individual objects only, no JSON structure)...**

```
{
  "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 1",
  "ObjectElementArray": [],
  "ObjectElementUnit": "2"
}
{
  "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 2",
  "ObjectElementArray": [],
  "ObjectElementUnit": "5"
}
```

**Output needed in this format (preserving the JSON array above the objects)**

```
{
  "Other": [],
  "Objects": [
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 1",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectElementUnit": "2"
    },
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 2",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectElementUnit": "5"
    }
  ],
  "Language": "en-US"
}
```

**Output needed in this format, so CSV conversion can be executed**

```
in2csv -f json --key Objects > output.csv
```

**Output CSV required**

```
ObjectElementName,ObjectElementUnit
Test ABC 1,2
Test ABC 2,5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want CSV, you should probably use jq's `@csv` filter, which essentially guarantees valid CSV output. For example, using your input:

```
jq -r '
  ["ObjectElementName","ObjectElementUnit"],
  (.Objects[]
   | select(.ObjectElementName | test("ABC"))
   | [.ObjectElementName,.ObjectElementUnit] )
  | @csv' input.json
```

produces:

```
"ObjectElementName","ObjectElementUnit"
"Test ABC 1","2"
"Test ABC 2","5"
```

However, if you're willing to take the risks, you could replace `@csv` by `join(",")`, which in the present case would result in:

```
ObjectElementName,ObjectElementUnit
Test ABC 1,2
Test ABC 2,5
```

Comment: Thank you, confirmed this works, but is there any way to keep the header row?  For example:

`ObjectElementName,ObjectElementUnit` with subsequent rows as....
`"Test ABC 1","2"`

Comment: Perfect :)  Solved