# Use JQ to output JSON nested object into array, before conversion to CSV

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

Use JQ to output JSON nested object into array, before conversion to CSV

Question is an extension of previous solution:

[Use JQ to parse JSON array of objects, using select to match specified key-value in the object element, then convert to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985676/use-jq-to-parse-json-array-of-objects-using-select-to-match-specified-key-value)

---

**Data Source:**

```
{
  "Other": [],
  "Objects": [
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test 123",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectNested": {
        "0": 20,
        "1": 10.5
      },
      "ObjectElementUnit": "1"
    },
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 1",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectNested": {
        "0": 0
      },
      "ObjectElementUnit": "2"
    },
    {
      "ObjectElementName": "Test ABC 2",
      "ObjectElementArray": [],
      "ObjectNested": {
        "0": 15,
        "1": 20
      },
      "ObjectElementUnit": "5"
    }
  ],
  "Language": "en-US"
}
```

**JQ command to extract [FAILS]**

```
jq -r '.Objects[]
  | select(.ObjectElementName | test("ABC"))
  | [.ObjectElementName,.ObjectNested,.ObjectElementUnit]
  |@csv' input.json
```

**Output CSV required (or variation, so long as ObjectNested appears into a single column in CSV)**

```
ObjectElementName,ObjectNested,ObjectElementUnit
"Test ABC 1","0:0","2"
"Test ABC 2","0:15,1:20","5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `keys_unsorted` and string interpolation, it's easy to turn `ObjectNested` into the form you desired:

```
.Objects[] | select(.ObjectElementName | index("ABC")) | [
    .ObjectElementName,
    ([.ObjectNested | keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\($k):\(.[$k])"] | join(",")),
    .ObjectElementUnit
] | @csv
```